# Zend render static / dynamic with multi controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-controller, zend-controller-router

I'm pretty new to Zend (read the documents concerning routers and controllers).

My `StaticController` and `IndexController` :

```
class StaticController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function displayAction()
    {
        $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('filename');
        $this->render($page);
    }
}

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();
        $this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();
    }
    public function registerAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

application.ini :

```
resources.router.routes.staticpage.route = /:filename
resources.router.routes.staticpage.defaults.controller = static
resources.router.routes.staticpage.defaults.action = display
```

My static content urls are : `site.com/faq` `site.com/privacy` `...`

These work, however others, such as `site.com/register` uses the `StaticController` rather than the `IndexController`, I can't say that I suprised by this behavior.

These static pages (about us, terms and cond...) need to be included in the zend logic for `.po` translation.

I can think of many diffrent ways to achieve this outside the Zend framework, but would really like to do it the proper *zend* way.

**How can I distinguish static and dynamic content, and still keep pretty urls?**

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. If you go to site.com/faq that should be loading the indexAction of the FaqController class. None of your example URL's should be going to the index OR static controllers.

Comment: I've added the application.ini. How can I distinguish static and dynamic content, and still keep pretty urls? –

Comment: How come you don't just create a FaqController and a PrivacyController that do nothing but render a view?  e.g. in FaqController `public function indexAction() { /* show view */ }`

Comment: @drew010 : a controller for each single static page ? really ?

Comment: Yes becomes a bit much if he has a lot of static pages, but it can simplify things if one of those static pages has to grow into something multi-page such as a faq section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way :

```
resources.router.routes.staticpages.route = "/:filename"
resources.router.routes.staticpages.defaults.controller = static
resources.router.routes.staticpages.defaults.action = display
resources.router.routes.staticpages.reqs.filename="(list|of|static|pages)"
```

If you don't know what 'reqs' is, it's very simple. For each param specified in 'reqs' you specify the regexp it should match in order to use this route.

But I personally would use an action per static page instead of a param in a single action, which would require this route :

```
resources.router.routes.staticpages.route = "/:action"
resources.router.routes.staticpages.defaults.controller = static
resources.router.routes.staticpages.reqs.action="(list|of|static|pages)"
```

It's planning that you may one day require different logic for rendering some your static pages

Comment: Thank you for this. Does the first method have any impact on reducing the overhead (compared to second)?

Comment: On the performance level there is no real difference, but i find the second more readable and maintainable. It's up to your own preference

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a prefix for static content so the router knows that you are trying to pull static content and not trying to reference an action in the IndexController.

```
resources.router.routes.staticpage.route = /static/:filename
resources.router.routes.staticpage.defaults.controller = static
resources.router.routes.staticpage.defaults.action = display
```